# Assign COUNT() to model field when projecting into a Model

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables that I wish to join on and make a model from: `Issues` and `IssueAttachments`.  One of the fields in the model is a count of all the IssueAttachments for each Issue.  In SQL, it's simple:

```
SELECT i.*, 
       ISNULL
       (
           (Select COUNT(IssueID) FROM IssueAttachments WHERE IssueID = i.IssueID),
           0
       ) AS 'Number of Attachments'
FROM Issues
```

But I'm having a hard time converting that to linq.  Here's my statement:

```
var issues = from i in db.Issues
    join ia in db.IssueAttachments
    on i.IssueID equals ia.IssueID into issAttachments
    from issueAttachments in issAttachments.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new IssueModel
    {
      IssueID = i.IssueID,
      /*** more fields ***/
      NumberOfAttachments = ???
    }
```

The `???` is where I need the count of `IssueAttachments` for each Issue.  I tried this:

```
(from ia in db.IssueAttachments
 where ia.IssueID == i.IssueID
 select ia).Count()
```

But I get the `Unable to create a constant value of type`  error.  I looked around SO for some examples but my lack of linq knowledge left me scratching my head on most.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
// Initially, we make a group of all the issue attachments based on the IssueID
// and we count the corresponding number of attachments.

var attachments = db.IssueAttachments
                    .GroupBy(x=>x.IssueID)
                    .Select(x=> new { IssueID = x.Key, 
                                      NumberOfAttachments = x.Count()
                    });
```

Then

```
// Later we join the Issues tables rows with attachments results based on the IssueID
// and we select the corresponding data
var issues = from i in db.Issues
             join a in attachments
             on i.IssueID equals a.IssueID
             select new IssueModel
             {
                 IssueID = i.IssueID,
                 /*** more fields ***/
                 NumberOfAttachments = a.NumberOfAttachments
             };
```

**Attention**

If you need to get values of attachments inside the more fields, you have to select them also in the group by we do initially. Please let me know, in order to update my post. Thanks.

Comment: I get this error 'The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'.  I believe it's because there are many issues without attachments.

Comment: @Robert where did you get this error? In the first query or in the second?

Comment: I have those statements wrapped up in a data layer, which returns `IEnumerable<IssueModel>` so it's happening when I try to call `ToList()` on it, like so `var issuesJoined = Repository.GetIssues().ToList()` and inside `GetIssues` is where I have your code from above.

Comment: Actually, if I just check for null and replace with 0, it works: `NumberOfAttachments = (a.NumberOfAttachments == null) ? 0 : a.NumberOfAttachments`  Now I don't know if that slows down the execution or not, but it's working :)

Comment: I am glad that I helped. I don't think that will slow down your performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = db.Issues
      .GroupJoin
      (
          db.IssueAttachments ,
          x=>x.IssueID ,
          x=>x.IssueID ,
          (i,ia)=>new
          {
              i.IssueID,
              /*** more fields ***/
              NumberOfAttachments = ia.Count()
          }
      );
```